# Kriging with gstat in R: Resulting object is blank with no interpolated values

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, kriging, gstat

I have kriged a dataset with the `gstat` package in R, but it has produced an empty variable as a result. I have 1,167 measurement points within a field, and I am trying to interpolate them across 3,464 interpolation points within the same field. How can I achieve a Kriged result with estimated values at each point?

Note: The input_data and interpolation points [can be found within a text file at this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VUtd0TxN_nh0YWVy55EZ2A_esWsSr392/view?usp=sharing); the contents within the file just need to be copied and pasted into an R window and run to generate the data frames. In addition, if desired, the field boundary shape file referred to later in this post [can be found here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZMP2kB0JLa2edvG_vFDPECee2VX-sqNT?usp=sharing).

These are the points that will be interpolated:

```
#Import libraries
library(pacman)
p_load(raster, 
       sf, 
       dplyr, 
       ggplot2, 
       scales, 
       magrittr, 
       gstat, 
       gridExtra, 
       raster,
       sp,
       automap,
       mapview,
       leaflet,
       rgdal)

#Graph points for interpolation
input_data %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  ggplot(aes(latitude, longitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = OM), color = 'red', alpha = 3/4) +
  ggtitle('Organic Matter Concentration') +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Convert data frame into a spatial object

```
input_data_sf <- st_as_sf(input_data, coords = c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = 4326)
crs(input_data_sf)

glimpse(input_data_sf)
```

```
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

The projection we are working with will be WGS 1984.

Making sure that the data was converted properly:

```
plot(st_geometry(input_data_sf))
```

[image]

That looks good.

Fitting the variogram using `gstat` and a Matern model:

```
lzn.vgm <- variogram(log(OM)~1, input_data_sf)

lzn.fit <- fit.variogram(lzn.vgm, vgm('Mat'), fit.kappa = TRUE)
```

The following warning message is produced after runnign the `fit.variogram()` command:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fit.variogram(o, m, fit.kappa = FALSE, fit.method = fit.method,  :
  No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?
2: In fit.variogram(o, m, fit.kappa = FALSE, fit.method = fit.method,  :
  No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?
3: In fit.variogram(o, m, fit.kappa = FALSE, fit.method = fit.method,  :
  No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?
```

Plotting the variogram:

```
plot(lzn.vgm, lzn.fit)
```

[image]

After generating the semivariogram, we now must convert the input points (the points for interpolation) to a spatial object:

```
int_pnts <- st_as_sf(int_pnts, coords = c('POINT_X', 'POINT_Y'), crs = 4326)
crs(int_pnts)

glimpse(int_pnts)
```

Visualizing the measured points and interpolated points:

```
#Read field boundary shapefile
shp <- st_read("field_boundary.shp")

plot1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp) +
  geom_sf(data = velv) +
  ggtitle("Sample points in field")

#Run this code if you don't download the field boundary
#plot1 <- ggplot() +
  #geom_sf(data = velv) +
  #ggtitle("Sample points in field")

plot1

plot2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp) +
  geom_sf(data = int+pnts) +
  ggtitle("Interpolation points")

#Run this code if you don't download the field boundary:
#plot2 <- ggplot() +
  #geom_sf(data = int+pnts) +
  #ggtitle("Interpolation points")

plot2
```

Finally, perform the kriging:

```
lzn.kriged <- krige(log(OM) ~ 1, input_data_sf, int_pnts, model = lzn.fit)
```

**The problem is here: When converting the `lzn.kriged` output to a dataframe to investigate how it turned out, both of the first two columns (var1 predict and actual) have `NA` values beside them. How can I fix this so I can graph my interpolation?**

```
#Convert kriged output to data frame
krig <- lzn.kriged %>% 
  as.data.frame
```

Answer (score 1):

When running the kriging I get some errors on `Covariance matrix singular at location ...` (see [Kriging with gstat : "Covariance matrix singular at location" with predict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394748/kriging-with-gstat-covariance-matrix-singular-at-location-with-predict)). That means that your data input has duplicated locations. I followed this `tidyverse` approach to dedupe the dataset and it just worked fine ;):

```r
source("input_data.R")

library(pacman)

p_load("sf", "dplyr", "gstat", "ggplot2")
nrow(input_data)
# [1] 1167

# Input data_sf dedupe
input_data_dedupe <- input_data %>%
  group_by(longitude, latitude) %>%
  # Just for illustatrion, you may sum or use another approach 
  summarise(OM = mean(OM))


nrow(input_data_dedupe)

# [1] 1165

# Ok, there were two duplicated coordinates!


# Now the rest of the analysis with deduped data
input_data_sf <- st_as_sf(input_data_dedupe,
  coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326
)
int_pnts_sf <- st_as_sf(int_pnts, coords = c("POINT_X", "POINT_Y"), crs = 4326)

# Variogram
lzn.vgm <- variogram(log(OM)~1, input_data_sf)


lzn.fit <- fit.variogram(lzn.vgm, vgm("Mat"), fit.kappa = TRUE)


# Krige
lzn.kriged <- krige(log(OM) ~ 1, input_data_sf, int_pnts_sf, model = lzn.fit)

lzn.kriged %>%
  as_tibble()


# # A tibble: 3,464 x 3
# var1.pred var1.var             geometry
# <dbl>    <dbl>          <POINT [°]>
#   1     0.646   0.0418  (-96.63478 39.1195)
# 2     0.417   0.0432 (-96.63515 39.11937)
# 3     0.812   0.0425  (-96.6346 39.12005)
# 4     0.654   0.0428 (-96.63523 39.12015)
# 5     0.654   0.0431 (-96.63568 39.12002)
# 6     0.686   0.0449  (-96.63485 39.1203)
# 7     0.905   0.0424  (-96.63453 39.1199)
# 8     0.633   0.0427  (-96.6352 39.12017)
# 9     0.657   0.0413 (-96.63458 39.11935)
# 10     0.853   0.0427 (-96.63548 39.11982)
# # ... with 3,454 more rows

ggplot(lzn.kriged) +
  geom_sf(aes(color=var1.pred))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate the help!